# Why is it Attach to root in Layout Inflater is always False value?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why is it Attach to root in Layout Inflater is always False value?

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret this as "add the child to the view immediately or later".
If you put true then you are saying add the child view to parent immediately.
If you put it to false you are saying add the child view to parent later.
Remember you should not pass true to this value when your are not responsible for adding a child to a parent.